# How to remove Grub from Surface Pro MBR?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have tried fixboot and fixmbr, both say "the operation completed sucessfully" however whenever I boot the surface, the logo flashes and than I am directed to grub's command prompt and the only way to boot windows is to type "initrd" as if booting linux and than press any key to exit, which boots windows.  This, however, is impossible to do when booting the tablet without the keyboard.  Ubuntu 14.04 is installed on an SD Card which I insert when I need to boot ubuntu, however grub must have been installed on the main drive's MBR.

Answer (score 0):

The Suface Pro is a UFEI machine, with a GPT partitioned disk, so the MBR does not enter into the boot process at all. Check the boot order, it should be USB, CD/DVD, then hard disk
entries for Windows, then Ubuntu.  That should boot Windows when the USB is not present, and the ubuntu entry on the hard disk should never be used.

The SD card should have its own EFI partition, and the bootloader used will be /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi, which should be a copy of shimx64.efi, and have grubx64.efi present in the
/EFI/Boot directory too.  The grub.cfg three line stub file should be put into /EFI/ubuntu (on the USB).  These three files should be on the hard disk's EFI in /EFI/ubuntu (where they will typically be put regardless of what location you specify for the bootloader at install
time). Copy them over and rename the shimx64.efi to bootx64.efi.

Do check that you have set up booting from the SD card in the UEFI settings.  The Ubuntu entry in nvram for the hard disk may be deleted at some point, it isn't used.  Any problems check what devices are used for the grub.cfg files (/EFI/ubuntu on the EFI partition and in
/boot/grub on the root filesystem.  The hd?s may need to be changed.